# c# null-safe navigator - internal implementation

Tags: c#

Recently I heard oppinion that C# null-safe navigator (`?.`) has influence on performance due to implementation via `try - catch`. It's very hard to belive that `?.` only wrapper like below but I can't find any proof about it.

```
try
{
...
}
catch (NullReferenceException)
{
return null;
}
```

Comment: That's complete nonsense and trivially provable as nonsense by inspecting the generated code of a function that uses `?.`.

Comment: I don't see why anyone would not implement that using a simple if/else construct. You got a source for the exception idea?

Comment: You could dig into it by just writing both the implicit version via `.?` and the assumed explicit version and look into the IL code with something like ILSpy or ildasm

Comment: It is nonsense. Read that article. http://www.filipekberg.se/2015/01/11/csharp-6-0-null-propagation/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is absolutetly not true. It is simply an if-else statement. [Try it out](http://tryroslyn.azurewebsites.net/#K4Zwlgdg5gBAygTxAFwKYFsDcAoADsAIwBswBjGUogQxBBgGEYBvbGNmfYsmANwHswAExgBZABQBKZq3ayZsto3IBeGBFQB3BpJwL28hZGQB+GACdUIYEWQxVpYwDo4fdKhGpkACz6CdBuT1FPggQPiJURwB1MzA0ABlIVDELKxsJXXYAXwMDThJyI3hXd08fPwkDFiDzT2AzCBgARky2HKygA==) using Roslyn and check what the compiler generates

Your Code:

```
public class C 
{
    public void M() 
    {
        C c = new C();

        int? result = c?.SomeMethod();

        Console.WriteLine(result);
    }

    public int SomeMethod()
    {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Generated Compiler Code:

```
public class C
{
    public void M()
    {
        C c = new C();
        int? num = c != null ? new int?(c.SomeMethod()) : null;
        Console.WriteLine(num);
    }
    public int SomeMethod()
    {
        return 1;
    }
}
```